# error when using ES6 classes with angular services/controllers

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I want to use ES6 classes in Angular application and trying to use it like this:

```
'use strict';

class EditorCtrl{
    constructor(){
        this.something = "ASd";
    }
    foo(){

    }
}
angular.module('Editor').controller('EditorCtrl', EditorCtrl);
```

but for some reason this code give me an error: `Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'`. Why is this happens and how I can fix this?

Angular: 1.4.7
Chrome:  46.0.2490.71

Comment: What exactly isn't clear about the error? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29641308/218196

Comment: It is unclear why this error appear and how to fix it. My example is the same as in solution you linked.

Comment: may be related to this issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12597

Comment: @klode, well I was trying to use also services in this way and got same error

Comment: The solution to your problem is in that issue also. it looks like they broke it in 1.3 for performance reasons (the answer that @FelixKling cites is obviously refers to older Angular version, 1.2.x).

Answer (score 2):

```
'use strict';

class EditorCtrl{
    constructor($scope){
        this.something = "ASd";
    }
    foo(){

    }
}
// Use this instead.
angular.module('Editor').controller('EditorCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    return new EditorCtrl($scope);
}]);
```

As the error informs must return 'new'. This way injection will also work.
Cheers.

Comment: This is not at all the recommended way to work with things (don't assign directly to `$scope`) nor the documented way (controllers should be able to be classes since they're newed up)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
angular
  .module('Editor')
  .controller('EditorCtrl', () => new EditorCtrl())
```